# What is the correct style for Fragment/Activity Interactions?

Tags: android, android-fragments

On an Android Project,
MainActivity with ViewPager and 3 Fragments:

1st page is fragment FindFrag.
Currently search query and display of results as list (in FindFrag)  is coded in MainActivity:

> accessed EditText in FindFrag from MainActivity, fetched query, formatted result, and displayed results in FindFrag from MainActivity ( the codes are written in MainActivity Class)

Is this the correct method?

1) Should I write it in FindFrag Class ?
2) How can I call methods in FindFrag from MainActivity (hook a method to an event in MainActivity) ?
3) Shall I use OnFragmentInteractionListener? 
 How ?
4) How to access views in fragments within the fragment class itself ?

**My app works successfully. My question is whether this is correct style/method in Fragment - Activity Interactions**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to code search query and display results in `FindFrag` , answer of How is you have to put layout code of `searchview` and `listview` or `recyclerview` in `FindFrag.xml` and copy your javacode from `MainActivity.java` to  Your `FindFrag.java`

Best way to access rootview in fragments is to use within fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

mainactivity is a separate java class, it should have a separate .xml file with a framelayout to show the fragments.

all other fragments should be in separate classes with separate .xml files.

use this tutorial its easy and clear : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/

Comment: I have separate .xml and viewPager to show all fragments. My app works without errors. My question is whether this is the correct style.